# Rails updating multiple Models of the same type in a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an issue where I am trying to update multiple models of the same type in a post. The first model in the loop gets updated but the rest don't for some reason.

I've posted the server log where you can see it finding and updating the first model and then just finding the rest.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what my issue is here? Thanks

```
  def special_save
    temp = params["_json"]

    temp.each { |h|
      hh = h['h_w']

      h_w = HourWorking.find(hh[:id])

      hh.delete('id')

      h_w.update_attributes(hh)
    }
  end   



HourWorking Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "hour_workings".* FROM "hour_workings" WHERE ("hour_workings"."id" = 187) LIMIT 1
SQL (1.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (3.7ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
WHERE a.attrelid = '"hour_workings"'::regclass
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum
SQL (1.7ms)  UPDATE "hour_workings" SET "end_time" = '2000-01-01 04:45:00.000000', "start_time" = '2000-01-01 01:45:00.000000', "updated_at" = '2011-02-10 10:18:19.955198' WHERE ("hour_workings"."id" = 187)
SQL (4.3ms)  COMMIT
HourWorking Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "hour_workings".* FROM "hour_workings" WHERE ("hour_workings"."id" = 169) LIMIT 1
SQL (1.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (12.8ms)  COMMIT
HourWorking Load (6.0ms)  SELECT "hour_workings".* FROM "hour_workings" WHERE ("hour_workings"."id" = 154) LIMIT 1
SQL (1.5ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.3ms)  COMMIT
HourWorking Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "hour_workings".* FROM "hour_workings" WHERE ("hour_workings"."id" = 170) LIMIT 1
SQL (9.8ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.1ms)  COMMIT
HourWorking Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "hour_workings".* FROM "hour_workings" WHERE ("hour_workings"."id" = 171) LIMIT 1
SQL (1.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (12.3ms)  COMMIT
HourWorking Load (6.2ms)  SELECT "hour_workings".* FROM "hour_workings" WHERE ("hour_workings"."id" = 165) LIMIT 1
SQL (1.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.6ms)  COMMIT
HourWorking Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "hour_workings".* FROM "hour_workings" WHERE ("hour_workings"."id" = 153) LIMIT 1
SQL (1.0ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.6ms)  COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to delete the :id key

```
hh.delete(:id)
```

Comment: In your paste, you delete the key by String ( 'id' ) not by symbol. ( :id ) You do too ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I have found my problem.

I had an issue where the params that I was posting were exact copies of what was already in the database.